# How to make nested re-usable fieldsets and use updateRecord to retrieve input and setRecord to load entered data?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, visibility, reusability

My app requires a lot of data-input from the user. And there's repetition, so for example the person fields must be filled in three times (all possibly different).

Person fieldset that I want to reuse

```
Ext.define('MyApp.form.PersonForm',
{
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    xtype: 'personform',

    config:
    {
        items:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'surname',
                label: 'Naam:',
                placeHolder: ''
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'adres',
                label: 'Adres:',
                placeHolder: 'Straat en huisnummer'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'zipCode',
                label: 'Postcode:',
                placeHolder: '1234AB'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'city',
                label: 'Plaats:',
                placeHolder: 'Of stad'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'country',
                label: 'Land:',
                placeHolder: ''
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'phone',
                label: 'Telefoon:',
                placeHolder: ''
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'email',
                label: 'e-mail:',
                placeHolder: ''
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

So I've made small fieldset and am trying to reuse them several times in the form. But when I try to load the saved data it concats all fields with the same name into an array of fields, so they don't get updated.

So instead of having one fieldset with others in it, each fieldset now only contains the fields directly in it. And the must all be placed in their own container so I can access them in the controller and update\load their respective data.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.form.UserDataForm',
{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires:
    [
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.field.Hidden',
        'MyApp.form.PersonForm'
    ],

    xtype: 'userdataform',

    config:
    {
        items:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                itemId: 'userDataForm',
                flex: 1,

                items:
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',

                    items:
                    [
                        {
                            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                            name: 'id'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'reportCode',
                            label: 'Meld code:',
                            itemId: 'txtReportCode'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'firstName',
                            label: 'Voornaam:',
                            itemId: 'txtFirstName'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'personform',
                name: 'person'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

The problem is that the fieldset directly in the panel is invisible (unlike when all fieldsets where nested in each other). So this only shows the personform. However the first fieldset is shown when I force the height to a set value.

Code for loading saved data and saving input:

```
onLoadUserData: function ()
{
    var userDataStore = Ext.getStore('userDataStore');
    var userDataRecord = userDataStore.getFirst();
    var userDataView = this.getUserDataView();
    var userDataForm = this.getUserDataForm();

    userDataForm.setRecord(userDataRecord);
    userDataForm.down('personform[name=insured]').setRecord(userDataRecord.data.person);
},

onTapBtnSave: function ()
{
    var userDataView = this.getUserDataView();
    var userDataStore = Ext.getStore('userDataStore');
    var isNew = userDataStore.getCount() == 0;

    var userDataRecord = userDataStore.getFirst();
    userDataView.updateRecord(userDataRecord);
    userDataRecord.data.person = userDataRecord.data.person|| Ext.create('MyApp.model.PersonModel');
    userDataView.updateRecord(userDataRecord.data.person);

    if (isNew)
    {
        userDataStore.add(userDataRecord);
    }
    else
    {
        userDataRecord.setDirty();
    }

    userDataStore.sync();
}
```

I tried using layout: 'vbox' and layout: 'flex' and or not using the flex: 1 on the containing panel.
So how do I get Sencha to show those fields when they are there, without forcing a specific height?

Edit: the problem seems to lie in using a form.Panel instead of a container. While the container will simply take the space it needs the Panel won't. But I need it to be a panel to get the loading and saving of user input working.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this seems to be two questions in one?

Comment: @ColinRamsay No, I can get the loading and saving of user input working. So long as I can use a Panel. There's just flexibility in answering, if you can provide another way of saving and loading input.

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code, it has two changes:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fek

I had to change the class name of hiddenfield and the xtype of formpanel to the ones used by Ext JS 5.

Comment: I am using Ext JS 5 but when I use xtype: 'form' it causes Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.form

Comment: Sounds like something strange going on - can you run this in your console and see what exact version you're using: Ext.versions.extjs

Comment: Ext.version.version = "2.4.0.487", Ext.versions.extjs = undefined. Does not look good. When I use sencha in the command line it always says: Sencha Cmd v5.1.0.26 and I also upgraded the app to this version.